# How to merge two rows of 2 columns into a single row of 4 columns without modifying the data entry?

Tags: tables, longtable, programming

[image]

At the beginning I designed a table with a huge number of rows of acronyms. The table has two columns and occupies `\textwidth`, as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array,xcolor}
\renewcommand*\arraystretch{10}
\newcounter{counter}


\newcolumntype\specifier{%
    |>{\centering\selectfont\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
    |>{\centering}m{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}
    |}

\def\row[#1]#2{& #1 \par \vspace{15pt} \textcolor{red}{#2} \tabularnewline\hline}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
\row[RAM]{Random Access Memory}
\row[BIOS]{Basic Input Output System}
\row[OMG]{Oh My Ghost}
\row[PS]{Post Script}
% and many more 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Later on, I thought it was not economical because it wastes too much paper. My new plan is to merge two consecutive rows into a single row of 4 columns, as follows.

[image]

### Constraints and Questions

First, I have a huge number of the following entries.

```
\row[RAM]{Random Access Memory}
\row[BIOS]{Basic Input Output System}
\row[OMG]{Oh My Ghost}
\row[PS]{Post Script}
```

Second, I am too lazy to use `regex` (to project these entries into other forms).

Is there a trick to accomplish my idea above without having to modify the huge number of entries given above?

Comment: Hopefully you understand my question. If not, please drop comments.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rephrasing some of your expressions. If I've misunderstood your intent, please edit further.

Comment: You are *too lazy* to use `regex`? I thought that's what `regex` were *for*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array,xcolor}
\renewcommand*\arraystretch{10}
\newcounter{counter}


\newcolumntype\specifier{|%
*2{
    >{\centering\selectfont\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
    |>{\centering}m{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1cm-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}
    |}
}

\makeatletter
\def\row[#1]#2{%
& #1 \par \vspace{15pt} \textcolor{red}{#2} 
\ifodd\value{counter}
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}

\let\oldendlongtable\endlongtable
\def\endlongtable{%
\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi
\oldendlongtable}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
\row[RAM]{Random Access Memory}
\row[BIOS]{Basic Input Output System}
\row[OMG]{Oh My Ghost}
\row[PS]{Post Script}
% and many more 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}

enter image description here
```

Comment: Of course one has to ensure that the number of `\row` entries is even.

Comment: @egreg if you want to be odd, now you can be odd

Comment: Just spurring you.